# Unable to find FullCalendar Date deprecation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to generate schedules. My date formats are special in that they're not dates, but they denote days of the week, like this:

```
"name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
"days": "MWF",
"times": "02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
"crn": "11215"
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46tnzj72/8/

A warning I've been getting in my console is this:

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:7002)
    at da (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:7484)
    at Ba (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:11268)
    at Aa (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:11165)
    at za (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:10886)
    at Ca (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:11581)
    at Function.h [as utc] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js:6:716)
    at ea (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:7084)
    at Ma.moment.parseZone (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:26684)
    at Ga.N.moment (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js:6:14265)
```

I've put debugger points through out my JS, and I just cannot for the life of me find out where I am calling a deprecated function or procedure. If you open the console in the Fiddle, the warning pops up as well. I suspected it was my `start.toDate().getTime()`, but I put a breakpoint immediately after its execution, and no such warning popped up.

I did the same throughout my JS.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Ok, so I taken out parts of the code to see WHEN I would get that error. If I remove the `events.push()` code snippets, I will no longer get the errors. Now that we know where the error is coming from, how do I fix the thing?

Comment: that notice comes from the moment.js library ... has to do with using strings that are non ISO like `2015-12-12` without an implicit format argument for the date parsing

Comment: I don't seem to be using any Moment functions.. Unless it's `.toDate`

Comment: but fullcalendar uses it now for all it's date handling

Comment: ahh.. True yeah. How would I debug where the offending function is?

Comment: use moment.js to set breakpoint perhaps , figure out where that message gets called first

Comment: @charlietfl Hi Charlie I found the source of error. It's stemming from `events.push()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop seeing the warning, don't load FC events with strings as dates. Use moment objects with explicit formatting strings.

Sticking this at the end of your `addEventSource` function in your jsfiddle gets rid of the error.

```
for(var i in events){
    events[i].start = moment(events[i].start,"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a");
    events[i].end = moment(events[i].end,"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a");
    console.log(events[i]);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/46tnzj72/16/)

---

If you're wondering what this error is about, it's a message warning that parsing certain types of date strings will be deprecated soon. The reason is mentioned [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407):

> using Date to create a moment from string, passed from the user is
>   extremely unpredictable, and it turns out to work somewhat and then
>   bite you in an edge case when you're not careful

So, when you use FullCalendar, use momentjs objects instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ok, so I see that once all classes have been pushed to events, you then loop through it again to convert the dates to moment objects, and then generate the calendar view. Does this simply stifle the warning, or does it completely fix the source of deprecation? Reason why I am asking that is, we still push the strings to the events. Also, wouldn't it be better to convert them to moments in the for-loop above so we're not doing multiple for-loops?

Comment: It turns all string dates into momentjs objects with explicit formatting strings. If you left out the formatting string (try it), then moment will try to guess what format it is and this generates a warning. If you pass fullcalendar a string date, it will immediately turn it into a moment without knowing the exact format and generate a warning.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected in the beginning. Back to my original question `wouldn't it be better to convert them to moments in the for-loop above so we're not doing multiple for-loops?`

Comment: Oh, didn't see the edit. Yes, you can combine the loops (not that there will be much performance difference). Personally, I use momentjs for all date handling since it's quite flexible.